How do I block certain videos on YouTube?
I would like to block certain videos based on keywords.
I found this question, which asks the same: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/66167/how-do-i-block-videos-by-keyword-on-youtube
but the answer is not satisfying and is from 2016.
I would like to do it on the YouTube app on an iPad.
I found a mention of admin.google.com that allows to do that, but it is apparently intended for organisations.
Does then iPadOS YouTube app allow for content blocking in general or If I sign in to the app with a YouTube account or subscription?

I was hoping it would be possible by managing the account on YouTube rather than having to do it only on the app.

Thanks. Let’s see if anyone figured this out other than “talk to the developer of the app and the provider of the service”

In the question text, you write "I would like to do it on the YouTube app on an iPad.", so not sure how to understand your "by managing the account on YouTube" comment. Can you clarify this with an edit?

I would like to manage the account so that there is filtered content and it reflects on the YouTube app. Secondary, if it is not possible to follow that, I would be happy to directly make changes to the YouTube app.

Asking about options available on YouTube.com is off-topic on AskDifferent.
